# How to config the grafana to dev enviornment

Tags: go, grafana

As am searching for graph UI, I came across grafana, the features are pretty good.Now i'd like to use grafana and contribute to grafana.I am a newbie to go language,can any body help me pointing me in any direction in setting up grafana to my dev env. I've seen documentation of grafana too.can any body help me out!!!

Comment: https://github.com/grafana/grafana#run-from-master

Comment: while doing grafana config, i got an error like "No command 'bra' found". how to rectify that!!!